# Does the time-independent function mean a random function?

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory

In control theory (or others) when the system is subjected to noise (or disturbance), the noise is often expreesed by the time-indepentent disturbance function $\zeta(t)$. Does this word "time-independent" mean that is random function?

Comment: The noise should be random because it's *noise*. Time-independent should mean that the noise looks the same *irrespective* of time - for instance that $\zeta(t)\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ as opposed to $\zeta(t)\sim \mathcal{N}(0,t\sigma^2),$ where in the latter case, your noise increases in intensity as time passes.

Comment: I think the correct term is stationary (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process). Basically it means current random sampling value does not depend on previous values, like coin flipping.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou you are right even I know that noise should be random but I wanted to know the relation - in meaning- between time-independent and random. now it is clear, thank.